# VB.Net shared constant strings

Tags: string, vb.net, module, constants

I'm refactoring a project, moving all the magic strings used to access the fields of datatables to a dedicated Module. This application has a lot of tables, with obviously even more fields, so my question is: is there any problem putting so many static constants (probably hundreds) in a Module, in terms of performances of the application?

Comment: There shouldn't be any performance penalty. Getting the strings from one place (the central module) is not really any different to getting then from another (the specific .vb file).

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. It will keep your code more organized.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would split the tables into classes and add them to the Module. You can then reference them in a more structured way, and the module will be easier to manage. e.g.

For a database named Person:

```
''' <summary>
''' Represents the fields of database table Person
''' </summary>
Public Class Person

    Public Property FirstName As String = NameOf(FirstName)

    Public Property Surname As String = NameOf(Surname)

    Public Property DateOfBirth As String = NameOf(DateOfBirth)

End Class
```

Then add that to your module:

```
Public Module Tables

    Public Person As New Person

End Module
```

To then reference:

```
 Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine(Tables.Person.FirstName)
    Console.WriteLine(Tables.Person.Surname)
    Console.WriteLine(Tables.Person.DateOfBirth)
    Console.ReadLine()
 End Sub
```

Or you could reference the object to make it slightly easier to read.

```
 Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim person = Tables.Person
    Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName)
    Console.WriteLine(person.Surname)
    Console.WriteLine(person.DateOfBirth)
    Console.ReadLine()
 End Sub
```

Regarding performance, the objects will be stored in memory but will have no real impact on performance.